# How to remove ubuntu after booting from live USB?

Tags: live-usb, bios, reboot

I am new to Ubuntu, even to BIOS. I am having a laptop with Win 8.1 pre-installed. To test Ubuntu I did this:

1. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
2. I downloaded Universal USB installer from PenDriveLinux.com
3. I created a Live USB and then rebooted.

The problem is, when I chose Ubuntu as Operating System from 'OS Selection', it gave an error saying a file is missing or corrupted in /ubuntu/.

The second problem is  I don't know how to remove that 'Ubuntu' from 'OS Selection'. I unmounted the LIVE USB but still its showing the option 'Choose your OS' whenever I reboot. I also tried by deleting the 'ubuntu' directory from 'C:// Drive' but did not work.

Comment: The 'Choose your OS' appears even you remove the USB stick from the computer? Unmount only works for the OS, BIOS don't know about it. If the USB stick is there, it will try to load it. About the error about the missing or corrupted, have you tried to load it again?

Comment: Yes, 'choose your OS' is still there even after I removed the USB. Yes, I tried to load it again and again but the error is still there

Answer (score 0):

Take the drive physically out of the computer, restart and all should be good.  Delete old Ubuntu ISO and download a new one,  the old one is corrupted.

Comment: I removed the USB, but nothing happening.